# When .img-responsive class is added to my images they stack on top of one another, any reason why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to get this layout correct and responsive, it looks good on my lg and md layout, but the sm and xs layout means that the images dont fit on one row. I therefore added the .img-responsive class to these images in the hope that they would resize accourding to the page, but it doesnt work that way, it just stacks the images on top of one another? Any ideas?

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="padding0left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-10" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <div class="row">
                <span>
                    <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="images/195x195.png">
                    <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="images/195x195.png">
                    <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="images/195x195.png">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean                           commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam                         felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec,                           vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer                         tincidunt. Cras dapibus.</p>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;>"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: .img-responsive means it will scale to the parent element. Without any of your code its impossible to figure out exactly whats going on or how to help you.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason my code snippet didn't show up correctly, its there now!

Comment: can you add your CSS as well ?

Comment: Theres quite a lot of stuff in my CSS, but I can't see anything that would be related, do you want me to add it anyway?

Comment: whats your css for .row

Comment: Don't have any CSS for .row at the moment

Comment: Your best bet is probably going to be resizing the image when the screen size gets less than XXX pixels using a media query.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The img balise must be close :)

```
<img src="LOLILU.jpg" />
```

Try that and give me news :)

Comment: Pretty sure img doesn't need to be closed:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: Euh sorry, i learn with that :/, can you post a little draw of your wish? please

Comment: I confirm:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly, at least try with closed img :) and give news

Comment: You've just sent me a link to a question, where the answer with the most votes says that you do not have to close img if you are using HTML 5 and the other are not needed within HTML 5 but can still be used?