# Is my "email me" button code wrong?

Tags: javascript

my code keeps saying this "Unterminated regular expression literal. (line 5, file "Code")" pls help
here is what I have:

```
<FORM>
</INPUT TYPE="button" 
VALUE="click here to add a game"
onClick="parent.location='mailto:1637206@student.ucps.k12.nc.us?subject=I would like to add a game to the website'">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your opening tag starting with a forward slash and no closing tag.

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" 
VALUE="click here to add a game"
onClick="parent.location='mailto:1637206@student.ucps.k12.nc.us?subject=I would like to add a game to the website'"/>
</FORM>
```

Start with `<Input` then terminate the tag with `/>`

Comment: Input is just `<input ... >` or `<input ... />`, not `<input ... > ... </input>`

Comment: so i should delete the word "form" on both sides and just start with              "< input"?

Comment: @AndrewGoodson, no, nobody said to touch the form tag.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara As far as I know, to keep with the HTML5 standard all tags should be closed and none should be left singular open.

Comment: HTML5 does not require single tags to be closed for void elements. XHTML requires self-closing single tags (ie. `<input />`). There is no opening-and-closing form of `input`. See [How to close <img> tag properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I see you are correct, especially in the case of the Input tag. Have made the change to my answer. Im still in WPF mode.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wobbles already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585085/1391325), the syntax of your `INPUT` element is invalid.

However, `'mailto:1637206@student.ucps.k12.nc.us?subject=I would like to add a game to the website'` is also invalid because you have spaces in the value for the parameter `subject`: It would be parsed as `subject=I` followed by gibberish which the parser wouldn't understand; [You need to encode special characters for it to be parsed reliably](http://blog.escapecreative.com/customizing-mailto-links/):

> Make sure you encode all special characters. Common character encodings are below, or you can use Eric Meyer’s URL encoder tool. If you would rather learn what all the character encodings are, you can use this resource.
>
> **Common character encodings**
>
> - space = `%20` or `+` (either one works)
> - line break / carriage return = `%0D%0A`
> - question mark = `%3F`
>     / (forward slash) = `%2F`
>     : (colon) = `%3A`
>
> You do not need to encode commas (,) or periods (.).

Comment: Though from a standpoint of good practice you should encode the url, it is not necessary. Most if not all modern browsers will handle the string just fine as it is.

Comment: Ah, okay. I haven't dealt with this stuff in quite a while, so I guess things are better now than they were back then ;)

Comment: I HAVE DONE WHAT U SAID BUT NOW IT SAYS "Illegally formed XML syntax. (line 6, file "Code")" HERE LOOK:myFunction
<FORM>
<INPUT/>; TYPE="button" 
VALUE="click here to add a game"
onClick="parent.location='mailto:1637206@student.ucps.k12.nc.us?subject=I would like to add a game to the website'">
  </FORM>

Comment: myFunction
<FORM>
<INPUT/>; TYPE="button" 
VALUE="click here to add a game"
onClick="parent.location='mailto:1637206@student.ucps.k12.nc.us?subject=I would like to add a game to the website'">
  </FORM>

Comment: @AndrewGoodson Did you even look at the answer or the code? What I posted is nothing remotely like what you are posting....

Comment: @AndrewGoodson Not to mention you aren't even commenting on the right answer.....

Comment: OK IM SORRY BUT...CAN YOU JUST WRITE THE CODE FOR ME..whoops caps..I just learned java and still am learning some so yea can u write the code and paste it..sorry

Comment: to the first answer?

Comment: Just look at [Wobbles' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36585085/1391325): It works. *Please*.

Comment: thanks guys sorry for causing  u trouble im only 14 and learning to code

Comment: The first and most important part of learning is defining very well what you want to learn/know... Only then can you go about learning it. Moreover, sometimes simply defining the question helps you find out the answer.

Comment: P.S. If [Wobbles' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36585085/1391325) worked for you (which it does), it's best to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) because not only does he get more reputation points but also you.