# Adding image source to JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I started learning JavaScript from zero, I used the *w3schools* website where I could easily compile the code without needing any IDE, etc... Now, I have moved on to using *Visual Studio 2010* so I am gradually learning more and more.

In [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb) example that turns a light bulb on and off, where is the bulb image stored on the w3schools website, so I can download and save it?

Now that I have a basic Visual Studio project (ASP.NET Web Application) that has a JavaScript and an HTML component, where should I store the bulb image and how should I reference it in my program?

**my JavaScript code**:

```
function changeImage()
{
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

    if ( image.src.match("bulbon") )
    {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    }
    else
    {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

**my HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title of the page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Header of the page</h1>
    <p>Content of the page</p>
    <p id = "demo">Click the light bulb to turn the light on & off</p>

    <img id = "myImage"
         onclick = "changeImage()"
         src = "pic_bulboff.gif"
         width="100" height="180">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you running your html off a server or just your local file system. You do not need an IDE for HTML/javascript development a simple text editor should suffice. If you are running it off your file system place the image in the same folder as your html file.

Comment: @NeilDCruz Thank you. I did that. But firstly, my `<img` opening tag is underlined, as if there is an error? Also, I can see that `pic_bulbon.gif` and `pic_bulboff.gif` are the names of the image files, so i should replace them with mine, but what does `match("bulbon")` refer to?

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match for the usage of match. It is used to match a regular expression and returns a boolean value.

Comment: @NeilDCruz Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry about using the Visual Studio for HTML/Javascript development.

Download the image and save it in the same folder in which the HTML file is placed. Or, you can make separate folder for image files and then write

```
<img src = "/images/image_name" id="myImage">
```

This is when the image is lying inside the folder 'images' which is placed at the same location where your HTML file is placed.

Comment: Thank you. I just don't understand why my opening `<img` tag is underlined, as if the syntax is wrong? `<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.jpg" width="200" height="300"</img>`

Comment: The `img` tag is called a void element, and hence it does not need to be closed. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly) question for more details, @Joshua

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried all those suggestions. None of the following resolves the underline indication; i.e. my opening tag is still highlighted: `<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.jpg" width="200" height="300">` also `<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.jpg" width="200" height="300" />` also `<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.jpg" width="200" height="300"></img>` also `<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="off.jpg" width="200" height="300"><img/>`

Comment: There could be some other sort of mistake, may be the tag above it is not closed or problem with some nested tags. If it does not cause any problem while running your application, then it could be any trivial problem as well.

Comment: @Joshua, if my answer has solved your problem as given in your question, please mark it as correct.

Comment: My problem still persists, as described in the comments. The `<img` tab is still underlined, I don't know why, and I still do not know where or how to download the image that w3schools refers to, or what exactly `bulbon` refers to...