# Adding Icons Onto Site

Tags: web, icons

I am coding a website and I have added all of the css, html, javascript, images, etc. Now, I can't add any icons. Where do I get these from? Do I download them from somewhere and upload them onto the server?

Any help is much appreciated!

Austin from Hexa Technologies

*This question refers to icons on our website and does not refer to closing image tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close <img> tag properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You can use font awesome.
http://fontawesome.io  ITS FREE, But if you want whole new packet you can buy it too. I don't have problems with the free version. ;)