# Responsive grid that expands items to fill hidden items

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, css-grid

I'm trying to make a navigation bar at the top of my website:

On a desktop screen, it should look like this:

```
+--------+------------------------------+
|        | WEBSITE NAME                 |
|  LOGO  +------------------------------+
|        |     LINK_1 LINK_2 LINK_3 ... |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

On narrower mobile screens,
I hide the navigation links
using CSS media queries.

The result looks like this:

```
+------+--------------+
|      | WEBSITE NAME |
| LOGO +--------------+
|      |              |
+------+--------------+
```

However, I want the website name
to fill in the grid cell
that the hidden navigation links used:

```
+------+--------------+
|      |              |
| LOGO | WEBSITE NAME |
|      |              |
+------+--------------+
```

How can I do this?

This is a MWE of my code:

```css
#header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 75px auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    align-items: center;
}
#header-logo {
    grid-column: 1 / span row: 1 / span 2;
}
#header-sitename {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}
#header-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    justify-content: right;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #header-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div id="header-logo">
        <a href="/">
            <img src="/img/logo.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-sitename">
        <a href="/">WEBSITE NAME</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="header-nav">
        <li>
            <a>LINK_1<a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>LINK_2>a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>LINK_3><a>
        </li>
        <!--- More links -->
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that your HTML is not well indented , some closing tag for `img` for example,
you can specify for your media query the behavior of the `header-sitename`

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header-nav {
      display: none;
  }
  #header-sitename {
    margin: 2rem;
  }
}
```

i've added a margin of 2 rem to be in the middle of the page when size is less than 600px so your website name fill the middle
you can check more about media queries in: https://learnjsx.com/category/1/posts/mediaQueries

Comment: [`img` tags do not need to be closed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492); I've left out the `src` attribute since it wasn't relevant to my question.  Thanks for your answer, but it only adds a margin around the sitename, while there still remains an empty grid cell where the hidden nav links are.  I'm looking for something that lets the sitename cell expand to fill the empty nav link cell, as shown in my question.