# In React, how can I replace a broken image with a default image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, I have:

```
<img className="article_link_image" src={article.image}></img>
```

I also have some JavaScript as follows in a separate file, which detects an image fail and returns either the passing src or a default src.

```
const image = new Image();

function testImage(url, className) {
  image.onload = imageFound;
  image.onerror = imageNotFound;
  image.class = className;
  image.src = url;
}

function imageFound() {
  return image.src;
}

function imageNotFound() {
  return '/generic.png'
}

testImage('http://example.com/image.png');

module.exports = testImage;
```

However testImage is asynchronous, and I don't know if is is possible to 'wire' it in to React

Comment: I would assume you have to set the `image.src` on error (inside your imageNotFound function), not return the value you want to have as the fallback image.

Comment: fyi, the `img` tag is a self-closing tag. That means, the correct way to use it is: `<img ... />` and not `<img ... ></img>`

Comment: @CornelRaiu Nothing wrong with using it the way he is using

Comment: @DamianBusz actually: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#technical_summary `Tag omission: Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.`. If it displays the image it doesn't mean it's valid HTML

Comment: `<img src='stackoverflow.png'></img>`
`<img src='stackoverflow.png' />` The following are valid XHTML tags. They have to be closed, as you can see they both are.

Comment: @CornelRaiu here you can actually see a very nice answer on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860596/7384132

Comment: @DamianBusz since we don't know if the OP cares about XHTML vs HTML5, I won't argue that. But the `must not have an end tag` in the link above is enough for me to always write: `<img ... >` or `<img ... />` :)

Comment: @CornelRaiu This is also related to react handling, mainly this https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/self-closing-tag.html

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
export default function App() {
  const imgToRender = 'https://wrong.com'
  const imgNotFound = 'https://placekitten.com/g/200/300'

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={imgToRender}
        alt=""
        onError={e => {
          e.currentTarget.src = imgNotFound
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

or to try something more advance

```
import { ImgHTMLAttributes } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Img
        src="https://wrong.com"
        notFoundSrc="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

interface ImgProps extends ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> {
  notFoundSrc?: string
}

function Img(props: ImgProps) {
  return (
    <img
      {...props}
      onError={e => {
        props?.onError?.(e)

        if (!props.notFoundSrc) return
        e.currentTarget.src = props.notFoundSrc
      }}
    />
  )
}
```