# Use an image in an Alert

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that needs to return a success message. But I want an image of a green tick in an alert box instead of returning a text success message at the bottom of the page. But after the script runs successfully, my alert box opens with a message saying that some script.googleusercontent.com says: (blank)

All of the below comes from the HTML file.

In the style section I have this:

```
#alert {
      display: none;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      border: 1px solid green;
      position: fixed;
      width: 250px;
      left: 45%;
      top: 2%;
      padding: 6px 8px 8px;
      text-align: center;
   }
   img {
      width: 10rem;
      height: 10rem;
   }
```

In the script section I have this:

```
var alertDiv = document.getElementById("alert");
      function invokeAlert() {
         alertDiv.style.display = "block";
      }
```

In the body section I have this:

```
<div id = "alert">
      
      <img src="https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1QPJ1fCWqsE_F-jYH_6L8loTFQr-k8H-J"> </img>
    
   </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `<img>` element is self-closing and does not need a `</img>`. Remove that.

Comment: [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close <img> tag properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly)

Comment: I fixed the tag but got the same result

Answer (score 1):

WeinerDog Alert:

gs:

```
function launchMyWienerDogs() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah2");
  t.alert = "Take Cover Weiner Dogs on the prowl";
  t.src = gobj.globals.wdsrc;//a global variable so I don't have to share my url with the world
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate(),"Alert")
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Alert - Weiner Dogs are coming</h3>
<img src="<?= src ?>" ?>
<p><?= alert ?>
</body>
</html>
```

image of dialog:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. I copied your code exactly to see if I can get your alert but nothing shows. I changed my success ondition to this:

`if (response.result === 'success') {
        launchMyWienerDogs();`

Also, I created a new HTML file called ah2 with your code in it, is that correct?

Comment: My if statement is in the other HTML file though

Comment: It was not my intention to provide you with a drop in replacement.  I had hopes that you could see how I created a dialog and thus be able to figure out how to get yours to work. I feel that it's a simply matter to create a dialog once you know how it's done.

Comment: It is unlikely that my code will work for you since I often use global objects that help me from having to redact private information from my questions.